# doveadm http API payload size

Tags: java, dovecot

I'm using [docker-mailserver](https://github.com/docker-mailserver/docker-mailserver).  I can connect to it using the [doveadm http API](https://doc.dovecot.org/admin_manual/doveadm_http_api/), which allows me to read messages and perform other tasks.

I can send e-mail using SMTP through Java. I want to be able to save the sent messages to a user's sent folder.  I do not have the user's password and am trying to save the messages using the doveadm API's command "doveadm mailbox save".  This works for small messages, but if the message has an attachment I get an error:

> doveadm(172.17.0.1): http-server: conn 172.17.0.1:56854: Client
> sent invalid request: Payload is too large

Someone had a similar issue and posted it to a dovecot mailing list but didn't receive a response.  https://dovecot.org/pipermail/dovecot/2022-June/124937.html

This user noticed that the dovecot code has a define

```
#define HTTP_REQUEST_DEFAULT_MAX_PAYLOAD_SIZE  (1 * 1024 * 1024)
```

This define limits the maximum payload to 1 MB, but the user was unable to see how to set the parameter.

I've looked at the [dovecot configuration pages](https://doc.dovecot.org/settings/#settings) and haven't seen any parameter that would allow me to specify the doveadm http max payload size.

Does anyone have any experience with this?  It would be surprising if dovecot provides the ability to write messages to a mail box but limits the largest email you could save using this api to one megabyte or less.